# Check if any user uses a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm going to drop a database. I want to monitor if any user is still using the database for a couple of months. Besides profiler, is there a better way to monitoring activities on a database?

Comment: I always just like to set the database offline and wait for someone to complain, at which point setting it back online is much easier than restoring a database you've dropped. The problem with monitoring for two months (or two weeks, or 6 months) is that you never know when someone is *about* to use the database. For example, does 2 months cover an entire business cycle? What if the CFO only runs some report against that database at the end of every quarter, or right before fiscal year-end?

Comment: Also see [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed).